# $content variable in node.tpl.php (Drupal 5)

Tags: php, html, drupal, layout, drupal-5

The `print $content` statement in node.tpl.php is causing my whole layout to break probably due to incorrect nesting of DIVs.

I want to check and fix that but I can't figure out what/where is the source of the `$content` variable in node.tpl.php file.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: As many have stated already, the $content variable gets assembled from many sources and is thus hard to debug. Can you post a `print_r` or `var_dump` of the $content variable from one of the broken pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$content` variable in Drupal nodes doesn't come from any one place. All enabled modules are able to add, remove, and tweak the `$content` variable, using Drupal hooks like `hook_nodeapi` and `hook_view`.

Knowing what modules you have enabled and the exact HTML that's causing trouble may help people help you more. As-is, the answer to your question is "it depends".

Answer (score 2):

$content is the variable that holds all the content. So it's difficult to pin point the exact location of the error with the nested divs.

However, the problem is most likely in a custom theme function located in your theme or a custom built module. Modules from d.o is usually free of such bugs, so hopefully you should be able to find the problem pretty quickly with the limited possibilities.

Another problem could be in the templates that's used to generate some of the content, again, you should only look at the custom made ones in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one place which will be the source of $content it can contain generated content from just about anywhere.

A way to debug is to turn off modules until the problem goes away and then work out what in that module is causing the problem.

Comment: Right, thats what I need to know, what nodes does content print and where do I find them to trace the error.

Comment: Any module may have hooks which cause things to appear or change in $content. As a result of this $content can contain just about anything. Generally it will be custom ones which cause the error but not always. Once you have isolated the module you will probably be able to see what has caused the issue. ps why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

The `$content` is what is returned from `hook_view()`

If many nodes are affected it sounds like it could be a custom theme function that is causing the problems.

Comment: I just need to find which block/function/file contents is it printing so I can check and fix validation errors. hook_view is in which file? Does it contain html that might have incorrect nesting?

Comment: `hook_view` isn't in a specific file. `hook_view` is a hook that any module can use to add to `$content`. Many modules do different things to `$content`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a debugger to see what contains the variable at a given time. If I remember correctly $content is the generated html content for the current node.

Comment: There are many 'nodes' or 'posts', difficult to debug. I'd rather find and debug the source html.